# T-SQL: Turn off certain Intellisense suggestions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, intellisense

Using Microsoft SSMS 2008 (T-SQL)

EDIT: To clarify, I am not trying to disable Intellisense completely. I am only trying to remove certain suggestions it provides.

Is there any way to remove certain suggestions from Intellisense?

For example, whenever I type 'or', Intellisense suggests 'OrigFinanceLab' and I always accidentally accept it by hitting [spacebar] and have to go back and delete 'OrigFinanceLab', type back in 'or', and cancel the Intellisense suggestion. It's really annoying.

This is not the only word it happens with, just one example.

I've looked at Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> Transact-SQL, but I don't see any way to remove certain specific Intellisense suggestions.

Comment: I thought *Intellisense* is very **useful** tool in `SSMS`.

Comment: I agree with you. I love it. I just hate certain, SPECIFIC suggestions that it provides. I'm only trying to remove/disable specific suggestions.

Comment: I don't think such options are there

Comment: @VR46 I suspect you may be right, though I hope there's some solution...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173743.aspx

Comment: @haytem Thank you for your suggestion. I actually found that page also, except when I go to the Intellisense setting, the suggestions are not listed there (for whatever reason)
 as the article describes.

Comment: Extremely annoying, but AFAICT there's no way around that.

Comment: In my opinion it is a better option to use a third party intellisense that actually works. The built in intellisense has been known as intellisucks by lots of people for a long time.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/583863b0-7d13-4900-b493-a6b107141107/intellisense-autocomplete-behavior?forum=sqlexpress Toggle Completion Mode or press CTRL + ALT + SPACE, that way you will have to select the suggestion first with arrow down

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to selectively turn off individual suggestions in SSMS IntelliSense.You should [post a suggestion to the SSMS feedback site](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback).

You can try out [SQL Assistant](http://www.softtreetech.com/isql.htm) in the mean-time though. It's a free SSMS add-in that provides excellent IntelliSense suggestions.